# Daily send to Hourly Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a new user welcome journey occurring on a daily basis which was originally built because our ETL process was handled nightly.  We've now changed that to an hourly ETL process so that I can welcome the new user within an hour of their account creation.

I'm wondering if an exclusion script would allow for a delay of sending follow-up activities in the journey closer to normal working hours.

I.e. if someone creates an account at 1am, i'd be happy to send them the first welcome email at 2am.  But, I don't want additional emails in the journey to be sent at 2am.

OR - would it be better to manage that occurrence in the JB `wait` activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wait feature in journey builder. In order to acomplish your use case, you will need to have a starting date (eg. my data source includes contact created date). See below for an example setup of a wait dependent on time of day. Once the contact journeys through this wait, all of the following intervals will be at a more normal hour of day.[image]